# Ошибка Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Делаю небольшое упражнение с девайсом. Пытаюсь сделать кнопку удаления юзера чекбоксом по айди. Вылазит ошибка:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
>   Couldn't find User with 'id'=edit_multiple

```
# routes.rb

root to: 'pages#home'
devise_for :users

get '/users', to: 'users#users'
get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show'  
post 'users/:id', to: 'users#edit_multiple', :as => :admin_edit_user
resources :users do
  collection do
    post :edit_multiple
  end
end

# кнопка в users.html.rb
<%= link_to "Delete", edit_multiple_users_path(:id) %>

# users_controller.rb

def users
  @users = User.all
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.nil?
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = User.find (params[:id])
  @user.destroy
  if @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "User has been deleted"
  end
end

def edit_multiple
  if params[:commit] == "Delete"
    User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).destroy_all
  elsif params[:commit] == "Lock"
    User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).each do |user_to_lock|
      user_to_lock.lock_access!
    end
  elsif params[:commit] == "Unlock"
    User.where(id: params[:user_ids]).each do |user_to_unlock|
      user_to_unlock.unlock_access!
    end
  end
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда внимательно читайте ошибки. Там на самом деле полезная информация. Давайте рассмотрим ваш пример.

Во-первых эта запись:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show Couldn't find

нам говорит, что мы попали в `UsersController#show`. То есть в экшн `show`.

Во-вторых, значение `params[:id]` равно `edit_multiple`

> User with 'id'=edit_multiple

Как так вышло? Давайте попробуем разобраться.

У вас ошибка в вызове, который формирует хелпер `link_to`, как заметил @Ilya Konyukhov. Вместо запроса `POST` сервер получает запрос `GET`.

Обратим внимание что роутинг в рельсах работает по принципу "первого совпадения маршрута" и дальше перестаёт искать.
Поэтому на наш запрос GET по пути `/users/edit_multiple.id` будет выбран маршрут

`get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show'`

и соответственно вместо `:id(.:format)` будет `edit_multiple.id`. то есть в контроллере `params[:id]` будет равен `edit_multiple` и `params[:format]` будет  равен `id`

Теперь попробуем исправить. Чтобы `link_to` формировал запрос `POST`, надо указать это в хелпере:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", edit_multiple_users_path(:id), method: :post %>
```

Ура мы попадаем в экшн `edit_multiple`. А `params[:id]` по-прежнему `edit_multiple`
При поиске подходящего маршрута роутер благополучно проигнорировал

`get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show'`

но нашёл первый подходящий маршрут для метода нашего POST-запроса:

`post 'users/:id', to: 'users#edit_multiple', :as => :admin_edit_user`

а согласно этому маршруту паттерн пути /users/:id(.:format). опять получаем `params[:id]` равен`edit_multiple`, а `params[:format]` равен `id`, а `params[:user_ids]` вовсе отсутствует.

а нужный нам маршрут:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    post :edit_multiple
  end
end
```

игнорируется.

Для того чтобы мы сформировали правильный запрос во вьюхе вызов `link_to` выполнить следующим образом

```
<%= link_to "Delete", edit_multiple_users_path(user_ids: @user_ids, commit: 'Delete'), method: :post %>
```

где **@user_ids** хранит то, что вы хотите передать в params[:user_ids]. Ваш способ вызова:

```
edit_multiple_users_path(:id)
```

вообще не определяет `:user_ids`, а определяет `:format`. Вспомните путь в маршруте `/users/edit_multiple(.:format)`.

Ну и наконец конфиг роутинга:

```
root to: 'users#index'
devise_for :users

get '/users', to: 'users#users'
get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show'
resources :users do
  collection do
    post 'edit_multiple'
  end
end
```

**Ссылки:**

1. про `link_to` вот [здесь](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)
2. [Роутинг в RoR](http://rusrails.ru/rails-routing)
3. [Devise](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/)

Comment: @jussbased, исправил пару ошибок небольших в своём ответе.

Comment: отлично, ошибка пропала. но кнопка удаления просто перенаправляет на root. вы не в курсе в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Не просто перенаправляет: в экшене `edit_multiple` после отработки происходит редирект на `root_url` -  `redirect_to root_url`

Answer (score 0):

Хелпер `link_to "Delete", edit_multiple_users_path(:id)` создает ссылку, клик по которой генерит GET-запрос.

Посмотрите таблицу маршрутизации приложения командой `rake routes`